# Create/edit group web-service in ELGG

Tags: php, web-services, elgg

I am looking for the webservice which would create the group. I looked at the available web service in elgg . I can only find the following web services related to the group -

Group

- group.join Joining a group
- group.leave Leaving a group
- group.forum.save_post Posting a new topic to a group
- group.forum.delete_post Deleting a topic from a group
- group.forum.get_latest_post Get latest post in a group
- group.forum.get_reply Get replies on a post
- group.forum.save_reply Post a reply
- group.forum.delete_reply Delete a reply

Do we have anything for create group web service in elgg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add following function, and its defination in your webservice file in `ELGG/engine/lib/web_services.php`

```
/**
 * The group.save API.
 * This API call lets a user to create group.
 *
 * @param string $name group name
 * @param string $briefdescription short description
 * @param string $description long description
 * @param string $interests tags comma separated
 * @param int $group_guid GUID of group if its edit request
 *
 * @return bool success/fail
 * @access public
 */
function group_save($name, $briefdescription, $description, $interests, $group_guid)
{ 
   //you can change/pass below parameters from POST
   $_GET['action']='groups/edit';
   $_POST['membership'] = '2';
   $_POST['activity_enable'] = 'yes';
   $_POST['blog_enable'] = 'yes';
   $_POST['forum_enable'] = 'yes';
   $_POST['pages_enable'] = 'yes';

   //include file at location "ELGG/mod/groups/actions/groups/edit.php"
   include_once '../../mod/groups/actions/groups/edit.php';

   //Or you can copy all code from that file and paste it here. And do modification according to your need.

}
```

Finally, you should expose a function like following:

```
expose_function(
        "group.save",
        "group_save",
        array(
                        'name' => array ('type' => 'string'),
                        'briefdescription' => array ('type' => 'string'),
                        'description' => array ('type' => 'string'),
                        'interests' => array ('type' => 'string'),
                        'group_guid' => array ('type' => 'int', 'required' => false),
        ),
        'User add/edit group',
        'POST',
        true,
        true
    );
```

Comment: You can do the same thing via plugin. See why: http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Dont_Modify_Core

Comment: @PawełSroka I am talking about web-service, so how can I create just single web-service to create group, because rest services are available.

Comment: @PawełSroka I don't mean to change the core, but if I use any web-service plugin then also I can add same function in that plugin file instead `web_services.php` My goal to show create group web-service.

Answer (score 0):

Paweł Sroka is right. you could make a basic plugin with a manifest.xml and a start.php in it and place your code in the start.php, and it does not matter wether you write a single function in it or hundreds.
for example you can take a look at the following plugin: https://github.com/markharding/elgg-web-services

Comment: I already rviewed all webservice plugins available, and finally I came to know that there are no web-service for create group. Please read my question.